# Room Migrations that have AFTER INSERT ON updates?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have an app that is used for testing outlets to determine they have appropriate voltage coming out of them.

I am using Room Database, and I am attempting to migrate from Version 1 to Version 2 of the database using a custom room migration.

The "issue" is that with Version 2 of the Database, I added in a new method for counting outlets in a room.  For instance, say a user skips over an outlet and wants to go back to that room to measure voltage.  In version 1 of the schema, the "new" test would be inserted at the BOTTOM of the list.  In a case where that user had tested 100 outlets, that's a nasty user experience if, say, the outlet was the #2 outlet.  Now their test cases are spread all over.

For Version 2, I added a method which adds a "child" reference # to outlets tested.  So, for instance, instead of them being number 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 in Version 1, they can now be named 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 2.0 etc...

I did this by adding in a `AFTER INSERT ON` to my outlet tests, as well as adding a few new columns to the table to account for that change.

My migration so far has worked, but now my child counter is broken, and I believe it's because the updated `AFTER INSERT ON` is not being factored in.

Is there a way to, within the migration, update an `AFTER_INSERT_ON` test case?  I have included the below migration code, along with the AFTER_INSERT_ON example that was included in the new Version 2 Schema.

```java
  /**
   * Migrate from:
   * version 1 - using the SQLiteDatabase API
   * to
   * version 2 - using Room
   */
  @VisibleForTesting
  static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
      database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Test ADD COLUMN is_child INTEGER DEFAULT 0;");
      database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Test ADD COLUMN from_import INTEGER DEFAULT 0;");
      database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Test ADD COLUMN child_ref_number INTEGER DEFAULT 0;");

      // VERSION 2 AFTER INSERT ON Schema
      //database.execSQL(
      //    "CREATE TRIGGER SET_REF_NUMBER_AFTER_INSERT_TEST "
      //        + "AFTER INSERT ON test "
      //        + "BEGIN "
      //        + "UPDATE test SET "
      //        + "ref_number = (CASE WHEN is_child = 0 AND from_import = 0 "
      //        + "THEN COALESCE((SELECT MAX(ref_number) FROM test WHERE session_id = NEW.session_id) + 1, 1) "
      //        + "ELSE ref_number end), "
      //        + "child_ref_number = (CASE WHEN is_child = 1 AND from_import = 0 "
      //        + "THEN COALESCE((SELECT MAX(child_ref_number) FROM test WHERE session_ID = NEW.session_id AND ref_number = NEW.ref_number) + 1, 1) "
      //        + "ELSE child_ref_number end) "
      //        + "WHERE id = NEW.id; "
      //        + "END;");
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that an option could be, instead of altering the table and adding the new columns, to :-

- rename the original test table table e.g. (`ALTER TABLE Test RENAME to test_copy`)
- create the test table as per the new schema

  - the exact sql can be found in the generated java in the class that is named the same as the class that is annotated with @Database but with the suffix **`_Impl`** in the **`createAllTables`** method.
- create the Trigger.
- then copy all of the data from the renamed original e.g. `INSERT INTO Test (the_original_columns) AS SELECT * FROM test_copy ORDER BY id`

  - note that **`the_original_columns`** would be replaced by a list of the original column names each seperated from the next by a comma.
- drop the renamed table (optional).
- **Note** *If the table being renamed has triggers or indices, then these remain attached to the table after it has been renamed.* as per https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

As such, as the Trigger exists, it will be triggered for each insert and thus  be applied to all rows. The **ORDER BY** clause may need to considered.

Here's a demo [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9eecb7/15907) that shows the steps (although instead of the test table existing and being renamed text_copy is is created directly, the important aspect being that application of the trigger i.e. the data selected showing that the ref_number is altered accordingly).

Comment: Ah, very interesting. I'll give this a try and let you know what I find!